# git-gui malfunction: can not create a directory or clone one

Tags: git, git-gui

I installed git and git-gui on my Mac yesterday (I'm a complete novice with Git). As I tried to use git-gui, I was neither able to create a new directory nor to clone an existing one from online.

However, as I tried cloning a directory through the command-line git ("*git clone [https://github.com/rickumali/RickUmaliVanityWebsite.git*"](https://github.com/rickumali/RickUmaliVanityWebsite.git*%22)), it executed successfully.

I tried reinstalling git-gui, but the problem persisted. What could be the issue, and what could be the next steps for troubleshooting?
Would it be reasonable to just work through the command line if  it seems difficult to get the GUI to work?

Here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR4XZ.jpg - please find the relevant screenshots: my attempts to create a new directory and clone a directory from online, the same error that appears in both of these situations, and the successful execution of cloning through the command line.

Appreciate any suggestions!

**Info on the system:**
Mac OS version: Monterey *12.2*;
git version is *2.35.1*;
git-gui version is *0.21.0.99.gdf4f9e*

Comment: Are there any extra messages beyond the blurb about setting a different default name for your main branch? If you give that a go maybe it'll show a more critical warning.

Comment: e.g. `git config --global init.defaultBranch main` to make the default branch be called "main"

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and let you know how it goes! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: As I see it, there's not much enthusiasm for git-gui on the part of the core Git folks, and you're probably best served by avoiding it entirely.

Comment: I changed the default branch name, and the error went away. I guess the error message was telling me to do just that. 
 
Isn't that confusing and hard to read, though! 

Mr Deeth, thanks for the solution. 
torek, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to put greater emphasis on the command line git.  

Question is closed.
Question